# I've this form data to be sent to insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

I can insert all fields in database except email field. I get the following error "Undefined index: em in C:\wamp\www\ins_db.php on line 11"
data type of email is below:

```
email varchar(20)  not null,
```

**Form code:**

```
<form action = "ins_db.php" method = "post">
<div class="reg"><br>
<br>All fields (*) are mandatory
<br>
User Id *<input type = "text" name = "id"><br><br>
Password *<input type = "password" name = "pwd"><br><br>
Confirm Password *<input type = "password" name = "cpwd"><br><br>
First Name *<input type = "text" name = "fname"><br><br>
Last Name *<input type = "text" name = "lname"><br><br>
Contact *<input type = "number" name = "contact"><br><br>
E-mail *<input type = "text" name ="em"><br><br>
Date of Birth *<input type = "date" name = "dob"><br><br>
<span>Qualification *
<select name = "qualification">
  <option value="B.Sc">B.Sc</option>
  <option value="M.Sc">M.Sc</option>
  <option value="Ph.d">Ph.d</option>
  <option value="B.Tech">B.Tech</option>
  <option value="B.Tech">B.Tech</option>
</select></span><br><br>
Experience *<input type = "number" name = "exp"><br><br>
Gender *<input type = "text" name = "gender"><br><br>
Address *<textarea cols="40" rows="5" name = "address">
Enter your address
</textarea><br><br>
Country *<input type = "text" name = "country"><br><br>
Religion *<input type = "text" name = "religion"><br><br>
Hint question *<input type = "text" name = "qhint"><br><br>
Hint answer *<input type = "text" name = "ahint"><br><br>
<?php
  $timezone = "Asia/Kolkata";
  date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
  $today = date("Y-m-d");
?>
ID created On *<input type = "date" name = "createon" value="<?php echo $today; ?>"><br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Following is the full php code which receives form data

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','jobhunt');
if(!$con)
{
echo "Can not connect to DB";
}
if(isset($_POST['id']))
echo "suceecess";
if(isset($_POST['em'])){
$em = $_POST['em'];
}
else 
echo "empty";
if(isset($_POST))
{
$query = "INSERT INTO seeker(sid,fname,lname,contact,email,dob,gender,address,religion,experience,qualification,created)
VALUES
('$_POST[id]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[contact]','$_POST[em]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[religion]','$_POST[exp]','$_POST[qualification]','$_POST[createon]')";
}
if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Fix your indexes! `"$_POST['id']"`, but better use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for a value in each individual POST variable. Replace your PHP code with this:

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','jobhunt');

    if(!$con){
        echo "Can not connect to DB";
        exit;
    }

  $keys = array('id', 'fname', 'lname', 'contact', 'em', 'dob', 'gender', 'address', 'religion', 'exp', 'qualification', 'createon');
  $query = "INSERT INTO seeker(sid,fname,lname,contact,email,dob,gender,address,religion,experience,qualification,created) VALUES (";

  foreach($keys as $key){

    if(isset($_POST[$key])){

      $query .= "'" . $_POST[$key] . "'";

    }else{

      $query .= "''";

    }

    if($key === end($keys)){

      $query = ");";

    }else{

      $query .= ",";

    }
  }

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$query)){
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }else{
    echo "success";
  }

  mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

As a side note, inserting straight from POST variables into a database is a serious security risk.

Comment: Yes email field is empty. But there's value in the form

Comment: I don't see a value in your current `<input>` for the email... I'm guessing you're inserting it yourself before sending?

Comment: I mean I've enterd email id in the form for it to process. But still it is empty !

Comment: yes I tested. It doesn't have a value. But I dont understand why when I do enter a value

Comment: And you're absolutely sure you've altered your current form to `name="em"` instead of `name "em"`?

Comment: Yes cent percent sure !

Comment: Can you post the full PHP code which actually builds the query and sends it to the server? Be sure to remove the sensitive information before posting (i.e password)

Comment: Yes I've did. Pls check

Comment: @Sam your POST variables are just strings? Have you actually tried inserting my code?

Comment: Can u pls check the second line of your code? Looks like it's incomplete !

Comment: Actually I tried changing input type of email to "email" in html. and now it's working fine. Still it's mystery why it didn't work before ! Thank you so much for your time ! Good luck !

Comment: There are no mysteries... You would do well to try and figure out why that works. Especially as you've had a lot of people try and help you today.

Comment: yup sure. Actually even the previous code works now. what to say? It's working fine with email as text type too. I think restarting the server did the magic !

Answer (score 0):

You have mised -> `=`

```
E-mail *<input type = "text" name "em"><br><br>
                                 ^ HEre
```

Should be like this:

```
E-mail *<input type = "text" name = "em"><br><br>
```

But you have to check either your `em` variable is set or not.

```
if(isset($_POST['em'])){
$em = $_POST['em'];
}
```

Comment: I tested your given code with else part added. And the prob is $_POST['em'] variable is empty ! I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: I did check! Yes the problem is em variable is not set ! But I have enter value for it in the form

Comment: Please check my updated answer i have mentioned that you are missing equal to `=` in your HTML at line `11`

Comment: Yes I've checked everything and corrected. But still no hope ! I am afaid I've to drop the email field totally to continue further !

Comment: No! try `var_dump($_POST['em']);` and check either it is empty or not

Comment: I did. The result is 'NULL'

Comment: Actually I tried changing input type of email to "email" in html. and now it's working fine.I'm not sure whether this was the mistake before. Now var_dum works fine. Doesn't show null.Anyway Thank you so much for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You missed an equal sign in the HTML code.

```
<input type = "text" name "em">
```

should be

```
<input type = "text" name = "em">
```

Comment: Thanks ! It was right at first.I changed names and missed = sign. I edited it. But that's not the problem.

Comment: I corrected as you suggested. But still there is error ! How can I fix it ?